# Disable global query filters *inside* another global query filter

Tags: entity-framework-core

Currently using EF Core 3.1 (although upgrading to EF Core 5 soon, so if this becomes easier in that version, I'm still interested).

I'm implementing some [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) to restrict access to entity data based on various criteria.

One of the filters operates on a type called "Encounter". An Encounter is linked to a single Person (via foreign key `PersonID`), but a Person can have many Encounters. The Person record has a navigation property to all linked encounters via `Person.Encounters`.

The query filter for Encounter is to restrict records based on the value of a particular property on Encounter (call it `EncounterType`). This works fine if my query filter is something like this:

```
x => x.EncounterType == "MyType"
```

However, I need to extend this logic so that an Encounter is allowed/loaded if **any encounter linked to the Person meets the criteria**.

So, the query filter for Encounter needs to be something like this:

```
x => x.Person.Encounters.Any(y => y.EncounterType == "MyType")
```

This does not currently work, because we run into a cycle and a StackOverflowException<sup>1</sup>; the global query filter for Encounter ends up expanding itself infinitely. (I think it's because we access the `Person.Encounters` navigation property and evaluate the same Encounter query filter for each encounter in `Person.Encounters`.)

What I really want to do is to completely disable the global query filter for any navigation properties used in this particular expression. In this scenario, I want to consider all other Encounters linked to the Person, without further filtering.

I know when actually running a query, I can call `IgnoreQueryFilters()`. I want something like that, but available inside the expression or when adding the query filter with `HasQueryFilter()`.

Is this possible? Is there any other way I can accomplish this with global query filters?

<sup>[1]</sup> *Which, while frustrating, is pretty cool for me...I've never posted a question about an actual stack overflow on StackOverflow :)*

Comment: Yeah... it's a cycle as cautioned for under the Note [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#use-of-navigations). Not much you can do about it I'm afraid.